# How to create an ipfs repo

Tags: ipfs

How does one create an ipfs repo in JavaScript without node.js?

I have some trouble figuring out how to create an in-memory store to pass to the `IpfsRepo` class.

```
var repo = new IpfsRepo('example', ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the MemoryStore available on the interface-datastore modules: https://github.com/ipfs/interface-datastore/blob/master/src/memory.js

Picking a different repo storage backend is done by the options in the constructor. You can se these on `new IPFSRepo()`, see an example: https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-repo/blob/master/src/default-options-browser.js

Answer (score 1):

i think you need use it  : https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-ipfs

for this you need IPFS node locally.

i hope is helpfull for you